# Python script results in internal server error

Tags: python, html

I'm working on a python script that generates html. Everything was working until I changed this:

```
i=1;
for lijn in open("enquete.txt"):
   slecht=0;
   for lijn1 in open("enqueteres.txt"):
      var=lijn1.split(":");
```

to this:

```
i=1;
for lijn in open("enquete.txt"):
   slecht=0;
   for lijn1 in open("enqueteres.txt"):
      var=lijn1.split(":");
      if var[3+i] == "slecht":
         slecht+=1;
```

Now I'm getting an internal server error. I tested the if test separately and it works. Here's my error log:

```
AH01215:   File "C:/wamp/www/Test/enqueteres.py", line 53\r, referer: http://localhost/Test/verwerk.py
AH01215:     if var[3+i] == "slecht":\r, referer: http://localhost/Test/verwerk.py
AH01215:     ^\r, referer: http://localhost/Test/verwerk.py
AH01215: IndentationError: unexpected indent\r, referer: http://localhost/Test/verwerk.py
```

Line 53 is the location of the if test.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I copied the code back into the editor as Alex suggested and it's working! I have no idea why because it looks the same as before. Thanks!

Comment: Copy the code from this question back into your editor.

Comment: That error message tells me you forgot a : at the end of your conditional. Did you copy-paste the code from your editor to here, or did you rewrite it? (I ask because it looks correct from here)

Comment: I copied it from the editor.

Comment: Are you mixing tabs and spaces by any chance?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 You can actually see the the presence of the ':' at the end of the conditional right in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a '\r' character at the end of your line. Try deleting the line and retyping it. Also I would suggest removing the semicolons, they aren't necessary.

Also ensure that you are not intermingling tabs and spaces.